# fuseki load graph - s-put not found

Tags: command, sparql, fuseki

I am trying to load a graph in fuseki. The server is working as it should.

But when I try s-put inside the fuseki folder it tells me s-put is not found?!

```
   hdeus$ ls
DEPENDENCIES        config.ttl      s-delete
Data            fuseki          s-get
LICENSE         fuseki-server       s-head
NOTICE          fuseki-server.bat   s-post
ReleaseNotes.txt    fuseki-server.jar   s-put
config-examples.ttl fuseki_config.ttl   s-query
config-inf-tdb.ttl  log4j.properties    s-update
config-tdb.ttl      pages           s-update-form
hdeus$ sudo ./s-put http://localhost:3030/ds/data default Data/books.ttl 
sudo: ./s-put: command not found
```

Any idea what the problem might be? I tried copy/paste s-put from the ls output but stil nothing... I am working in mac os X

Answer (score 4):

Is the file executable?  If you unpacked from the zip file, you need to set the s-* executable. Also, you need ruby installed.